# Mixed-characters strings to ordered list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently jumped into python and, with the help of a similar script, wanted to "grab" and parse my region's commuter train infos.

The thing is, the infos I get are a big chunk of already ordered and tagged indications, but despite my searches (and due to my poor programming level), I can't seem to find a way to digest it.

You can find an example of what I get [here](http://sncf.mobi/infotrafic/iphoneapp/transilien/?gare=BEC).

And what my "code" currently looks like :

```
import urllib
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://sncf.mobi/infotrafic/iphoneapp/transilien/?gare=BEC")
htmlSource = sock.read()
sock.close()
o = htmlSource
print o
```

The ideal would be to be able work with each train's infos easily, to combine them with their respective stations, types, etc.

Many thanks, if there is anything I can do to improve my submission, I'll be happy to do it.

Comment: Checkout BeautifulSoup.  It makes parsing and sifting through HTML a lot more pleasant.

Comment: The response appears to be json, not html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, the response is in JSON. Python comes with a library for parsing JSON, so you just need to use it to get a nice structure of dicts, lists and strings:

```
import urllib
import json

response = urllib.urlopen("http://sncf.mobi/infotrafic/iphoneapp/transilien/?gare=BEC")
if response.getcode() == 200:
    data = json.load(response)
    for train in data["D"]:
        print "Train number", train["numerotrain"], "code", train["codevoyageur"]
else:
    print "Failed to load data:", response.getcode()
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I'll try to be more thorough with my searches next time.

Answer (score 2):

Since the page you are linking to contains JSON and not HTML, I would suggest parsing it with the `json` module. You could do something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

with urlopen('http://sncf.mobi/infotrafic/iphoneapp/transilien/?gare=BEC') as sock:
    information = json.loads(sock.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

and then `information` contains all the information on the page in a Python dictionary.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot but I can't make your solution work... I always get this error message :

_AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__exit__'_

Comment: @kr0osti It should work, but only in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If the wrapper is always `D` or you know what the wrapper is...

```
import json

class Trains:
    def __init__(self, data, wrapper='D'):
        self.data = data[wrapper]

    def get_train_by_number(self, num):
        for i in self.data:
            if int(i['numerotrain']) == num: return i
        return None

# your code to pull http://sncf.mobi/infotrafic/iphoneapp/transilien/?gare=BEC

data = json.loads(response)
trains = Trains(data)

# get train number 134741
train = trains.get_train_by_number(134741)

print train['heureprobable'] # prints 11/06/2013 00:54
```